# xslt selection: if there is at least one descendant without a certain criteria

Tags: xslt-2.0

I try to select paragraphs with no italic text in them (xslt 2.0):

```
<p>Some <hi rend="italic">italic text</hi></p>
<p>Some <hi rend="bold">bold text</hi> and some <hi rend="italic">italic Text</hi></p>
<p>Some <hi rend="bold">bold text</hi></p>
```

I only want to have p[3]. I tried this and it works:

```
  <xsl:template match="p">
     <xsl:if test="p[not(child::hi[@rend='italic'])]"> ... do something </if>
  </xsl:template>
```

But my real problem is to move this one level deeper: I want only those texts with *at least* one paragraph with no italic text:

```
<text>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some <hi rend="bold">text</hi> and some <hi rend="italic">italic</hi> text</p>
</text>
<text>
    <p>Some <hi rend="bold">text</hi></p>
    <p>Some other text</p>
</text>
<text>
    <p>Some <hi rend="italic">text</hi></p>
    <p>Some <hi rend="italic">text</hi></p>
</text>
```

How can i select the first two texts but not the third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you simply want

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(hi[@rend = 'italic'])]">...</xsl:template>
```

For the second part

```
<xsl:template match="text[p[not(hi[@rend = 'italic'])]]">...</xsl:template>
```